# chrome.storage.local.set using a variable key name

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

In a Google Chrome Extension, I want to use [`chrome.storage.local`](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/storage.html#property-local) (as opposed to localStorage) because:

1. With key-value pairs, the value can be any object (as opposed to string only)
2. Changes to the data model using setter `storage.set` can trigger an event listener

Using `storage.set`, how can I have a variable key name?

Note: If I don't use the setter, I can do `storage[v1]`, but changes to the object won't trigger the event listener.

```
var storage = chrome.storage.local;
var v1 = 'k1';

storage.set({v1:'s1'});

storage.get(v1,function(result){
    console.log(v1,result);
    //console output = k1 {}
});
storage.get('v1',function(result){
    console.log(result);
    //console output = {v1:'s1'}
});
```

Comment: In case this helps...

storage.set =
function () {
        var schema = this.parameters[functionName];
        chromeHidden.validate(arguments, schema);
        return sendRequest(
            'storage.' + functionName,
            [namespace].concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)),
            extendSchema(schema));
      }

Comment: @Pacerier I'm wondering what was the reason behind taking time to edit the question and 2 answers just to refactor 1 variable name.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Is this what you where looking for?

```
var storage = chrome.storage.local;

var v1 = 'k1';

var obj= {};

obj[v1] = 's1';

storage.set(obj);

storage.get(v1,function(result){
  console.log(v1,result);
  //console output = k1 {v1:'s1'}
});

storage.get('v1',function(result){
  console.log(result);
  //console output = {v1:'s1'}
})
```

Answer (score 30):

It's 2016, and Chrome (and Firefox, and Edge - everyone using Chrome extension model) support ES6 [Computed Property Names](http://es6-features.org/#ComputedPropertyNames).

With that, the task becomes simpler:

```
var storage = chrome.storage.local;
var v1 = 'k1';

storage.set({
  [v1]: 's1' // Will evaluate v1 as property name
});

storage.get(v1, (result) => {
    console.log(v1, result[v1]);
});
```

Comment: Should `storage.set({ k1: 's1' });` work too? Because in my case it's nesting a k1 key inside the value of the last k1 key each time I run the set!