# Chrome Extension "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier" on `storageArea.set`

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

```js
var getShortenedUrl = function () {

  chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function (tab) {

    var request_data = {
      'command': 'generate',
      'params': {
        'url': tab.url,
        'code': text_field.value
      }
    }

    chrome.extension.sendRequest(request_data, function (data) {
      switch (data.status) {
        case 'OK':
          setTextField(data.shortened_url)
          bindBtnToCoopy()
          chrome.storage.local.get(data.shortened_url, function (arr) {
            if (!arr[data.shortened_url]) {
              chrome.storage.local.set(
                {data.shortened_url:
                 tab.url}) /* <-- this thing throws an error */
            }
          })
          break
          /* ... */
      }
    })
  })
}
```

see https://github.com/noformnocontent/git-io-chrome/blob/master/chrome/popup.js#L96

---

and if i comment the `chrome.storage.local.set` part out, everything is "perfect"

Comment: Your line wraps are adventurous. And use semicolons!

Comment: possible duplicate of [chrome.storage.local.set using a variable key name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11692699/chrome-storage-local-set-using-a-variable-key-name)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as in the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11692699/chrome-storage-local-set-using-a-variable-key-name) @pimvdb mentioned, to save an object, i must use an Object.

```js
if (!arr[data.shortened_url]) {
  var urlPair = {}
  urlPair[data.shortened_url] = tab.url
  chrome.storage.local.set(urlPair)
}
```

---

since then i also released the v.0.5 of “Git.io for Chrome”, see http://git.io/crome for more