# Using a variable key in chrome.storage.local.set

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-storage

I am creating a chrome-extension. 
I don't know how to use a variable as the key to `chrome.storage.local.set()` function. I have tried

```
var key = 'myKey';
chrome.storage.local.get(key, function(val) { 
    chrome.storage.local.set({key:val[key]+param1}); //appending  param1
    alert(val[key]);
}
```

Here i am trying to get the value of `val[key]` and append a string `param1` and place it back   to the storage using the same key. But I am not able to do so.
 the alert box displays undefined all the time.

---

But when I try without the variable `key` , **it works fine**.

```
chrome.storage.local.get('myKey', function(val) { 
    chrome.storage.local.set({myKey:val['myKey']+param1}); //appending  param1
    alert(val['myKey']);
}
```

The problem is that I am using `chrome.storage.local.set` can have arguments of not only string but also objects.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have solved the problem.
Instead of using `chrome.storage.local.set({key:val[key]+param1});`

I have replaced the json string `{key:val[key]+param1}` with an object.

```
var obj = {};       
var key = "myKey";  
obj[key] += param1;   
chrome.storage.local.set(obj);
```

Here `obj` has value `{"myKey":"the appended value"}`

Comment: also look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11694909/1213961)

Answer (score 6):

In JavaScript, the only way to use a non-static variable name is by assigning a value as a property, instead of using object literals.

```
var key = 'myKey';
var param1 = 'whatever';
chrome.storage.local.get(key, function(val) {
    // Create property if does not exist (yet)
    if (typeof val[key] != 'string') val[key] = '';
    // Append value of param1
    val[key] += param1;
    // Save data
    chrome.storage.local.set(val);
    alert(val[key]);
});
```

Note: You might want to verify that [`set`](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage.html#method-StorageArea-set) succeeded.  This can be done by using a callback. For instance:

```
    chrome.storage.local.set(val, function() {
        if (chrome.extension.lastError) {
            alert('An error occurred: ' + chrome.extension.lastError.message);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Great but it do not look if the val is already there and duplicate the same value many time

Comment: Might want to update this to ES6 computed property names.

Comment: Or, dupehammer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11692699/chrome-storage-local-set-using-a-variable-key-name/40287132) if you don't want to update.