# chrome.storage.local.get results in "Undefined" when called

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm building a chrome extension, and I needed to save some data locally; so I used the [Storage API](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage.html) . I got to run the simple example and save the data, but when I integrated it with my application, it couldn't find the data and is giving me "Undefined" result.

Here is my Code:

```
    function saveResults(newsId, resultsArray) {
//Save the result
        for(var i = 0; i < resultsArray.length; i++) {
            id = newsId.toString() + '-' + i.toString();
            chrome.storage.local.set({ id : resultsArray[i] });
        }
//Read and delete the saved results
        for(var i = 0; i < resultsArray.length; i++) {
            id = newsId.toString() + '-' + i.toString();
            chrome.storage.local.get(id, function(value){
                alert(value.id);
            });
            chrome.storage.local.remove(id);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I think it should be just `alert(value);` and not `alert(value.id);`

Comment: For getting: Use `value[id]` instead of `value.id`. For setting, see [Using a variable key in chrome.storage.local.set](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14983500/938089 "Answer: Using a variable key in chrome.storage.local.set")

Comment: when I say "alert(value)" it gives me this "object Object" in the alert box.

Comment: when using "value[id]" it results in "undefined" also

Comment: @IbrahimAwad The `chrome.storage` API is fully asynchronous. You have to restructure your code to get it to work.

Comment: @Rob W: I tried to wait a certain period of time (5 sec) after saving the data, then retrieving it; it didn't work also. Any suggestions ?

Comment: @IbrahimAwad Don't hard-code a timed delay, make use of the callbacks provided by the `get` and `set` methods. To address your last question: Have you already followed the advice from my first comment? Ie, read [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14983500/938089)?

Comment: @Rob W : I don't know what's wrong, the problem seems fairly simple and yet it won't work. I've decided to redesign the code hoping that it works. Thanks any way for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I am not certain what type of data you are saving or how much, but it seems to me that there may be more than one `newsId` and a `resultsArray` of varying length for each one. Instead of creating keys for each element of `resultsArarry` have you considered just storing the entire thing as is. An example of this would be:

```js
chrome.storage.local.set({'results':[]});

function saveResults(newsId, resultsArray) {
  // first combine the data into one object
  var result = {'newsId':newsId, 'resultsArray':resultsArray};

  // next we will push each individual results object into an array
  chrome.storage.get('results',function(item){
    item.results.push(result);
    chrome.storage.set({'results':item.results});
  });
}

function getResults(newsId){
  chrome.storage.get('results', function(item){
    item.results.forEach(function(v,i,a){
      if(v.newsId == newsId){
        // here v.resultsArray is the array we stored
        // we can remove any part of it such as
        v.resultsArray.splice(0,1);
        // or
        a.splice(i,1);
        // to remove the whole object, then simply set it again
        chrome.storage.local.set({'results':a});
      }
    });
  });
}
```

This way you don't need to worry about dynamically naming any fields or keys.

Comment: I read your answer and redesigned the code. It still doesn't work and I don't know why. Here it is:

`function saveResults(newsId, resultsArray) {
 chrome.storage.local.set({newsId: resultsArray});
}

function Load(newsId) {
 chrome.storage.local.get(newsId, function(result){
  var channel = result.newsId;
  console.debug('result: ', channel);
 });
}`

Answer (score 1):

First of All thanks to Rob and BreadFist and all you guys. I found out why my code wasn't working.
Storage.Set doesn't accept the key to be an 'integer' and even if you try to convert that key to be a 'string' it won't work too. So I've added a constant character before each key and it worked. Here's my code.

```
function saveResults(Id, resultsArray) {
    var key = Id.toString();
    key = 'a'.key;
    chrome.storage.local.set({key : resultsArray});
}

function Load(Id) {
    var key = Id.toString();
    key = 'a'.key;
    chrome.storage.local.get(key, function(result){
        console.debug('result: ', result.key);
    });
}
```