# chrome.storage.sync.set not saving values

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, local-storage

So I've run into a bit of snag with regards to local storage on Google Chrome. From what I've researched, my syntax seems to be correct, but for some reason the value is not being saved. Here's my code:

```
chrome.storage.sync.get(accName, function(data) {
    var accData = data[accName];
    // Stuff
    chrome.storage.sync.set({ accName: accData }, function() {
        alert('Data saved');
    });
});
```

Every time I re-run it, `data[accName]` returns undefined. I've tried the same code with literal values for the sync.set parameters (eg. `{ 'john32': ['fk35kd'] }`), and that seems to work, so I'm really confused as to what the issue could be. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using a variable key in chrome.storage.local.set](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14982560/using-a-variable-key-in-chrome-storage-local-set) (the problem is caused by a wrong method to set the value, your getter is OK.)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The issue was trying to plug `accName` into an object literal inside the set statement (credit to [Rob](https://stackoverflow.com/users/938089/rob-w) above). What I'd end up with was an object with a property 'accName' rather than the value of `accName` itself. Here's a fix.

```
var obj = {};
obj[accName] = accData;
chrome.storage.sync.set(obj, function() {
    alert('Data saved');
});
```

**Update**

ES6 now allows [computed property names in object literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names), so the above can be achieved with:

```
chrome.storage.sync.set({ [accName]: accData }, function() {
    alert('Data saved');
});
```

Comment: can i set multiple values like that?

Comment: @Unnikrishnan Not in a single statement that I'm aware.

Comment: `obj[accName] = accData;` here you set only one value, can we add more values here?

Comment: @Unnikrishnan Only with subsequent statements of the same manner.

Comment: Apparently you can also do the following: 
chrome.storage.sync.set({ [accName]: accData }, ...)