# JS: Chrome Storage: value isn't saved

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am developing a chrome extension for my personal use. I have a popup with a few settings to be saved (to be more specific I want to save IDs).

The permissions `tabs` and `storage` are set.

So I am using chrome's build-in storage API to set and get my values:
I want to save 3 different values:

`chrome.storage.sync.set({ 'course': this.value });` and

`chrome.storage.sync.set({ 'group': this.value, 'name': name});`

`course` and `group` are saved, but `name` isn't.

So my question is why `name` isn't saved and what I am doing wrong. Thanks for the help.

**EDIT 1:**

On my content script I get the data like that:

`chrome.storage.sync.get(null, function(data) {
    console.log(data);
});`

`null` to get all keys. My console logs: `{course: "1424", group: "5296"}`. No sign of the key `name`.

**EDIT 2:**

Due to Ty Q's suggestion to use

`var obj = {};
 obj['group'] = this.value;
 obj['name'] = name;
 chrome.storage.sync.set(obj);`

the saving now works!

Comment: are you sure it isn't supposed to be `this.name`? You didn't provide all of the code, granted I'm not too familiar with Chrome extension development, it sure would be nice knowing what the rest of your [relevant] code looks like.

Comment: this. isn't needed. I can put there what i want. It doesn't matter. The valie isn't getting saved. I can add some more information if you want.

Comment: Idk. Like, where are you getting the value `name`? Also, this *might* help you out? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17331957/chrome-storage-sync-set-not-saving-values

Comment: Thank you! It worked with the link you provided.

Answer (score 0):

See **EDIT 2** for the solution.

Creating an object and filling it with data before saving the object to the storage worked very well!

Thank you @Ty Q.