# Remove variables starting with a string from chrome.storage.local in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, string, google-chrome-extension, local-storage

In a chrome extension, I store some variables in chrome.storage.local like this: `chrome.storage.local.set({["name" + counter]: ""}, function() {});` (many thanks to Xan's answer regarding ES6 computed property names [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40287132/8418085)), where `counter` is basically an incremented number.

How can I use `chrome.storage.local.remove` to remove all the variables starting with "name" that were previously stored, when I don't need them anymore?

Note: I use this type of storage ("name0", "name1", ...) as I can't store them as an array and update it on the fly in `chrome.storage.local` (I have to first get the array, update it, then store it back, which is unsuitable for large amounts of data). Also, in the case of a new extension execution, I don't know the maximum `counter` value, so I'm not able to use it within a `for` loop.

Comment: Are the variable names you're storing sequential in that you would never find two variables more than 1 apart e.g. `..., name4, name6, name7`?

Comment: In my current implementation, yes they are (although I'm not sure if I will keep this approach later on).

Comment: Okay, well one way to remove all of the variables beginning with 'name' is to keep an array of all of the names you're adding. Removing them would be as easy `chrome.storage.local.remove(variablesNames)`. You might want to store this array in storage if your needs require.

Comment: Thank you for your first comment - this gave me the idea of testing for errors in the callback of the `remove` function, as I mentioned in my comment to Chay22's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was trying to put this on a comment since things are outside my capability. But since this gives proper formatting, so.

I looked at [`chrome.storage`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage#type-StorageArea) that if you pass `null` to first parameter, you'll get the entire values. So by provide a callback to it, it becomes

```
chrome.storage.local.get(null, function (items) {
    for (var key in items) {
        if (key.startsWith('name')) { // or key.includes or whatever
            chrome.storage.local.remove(key)
        }
    }
})
```

Since items stored might big enough, storing keys inside another key name would work perhaps.
Example of wrapper functions

```
function set(key, value) {
    var collectionOfKeys = chrome.storage.local.get('collection_of_keys') || []

    collection_of_keys.push(key)

    chrome.storage.local.set('collection_of_keys', collection_of_keys)
    chrome.storage.local.set('name' + key, value)
}
```

To remove

```
chrome.storage.local.remove(chrome.storage.local.get('collection_of_keys'))
```

Well, dumb enough if the size of keys is still big.

In case you keep it in sequence, maybe track the length of it will do.

```
function set(key, value) {
    var collectionOfKeyLength = chrome.storage.local.get('collection_of_key_length') || 0

    chrome.storage.local.set('collection_of_key_length', collectionOfKeyLength + 1)
    chrome.storage.local.set('name' + key, value)
}

function remove () {
    for (var i = 0; i < chrome.storage.local.get('collection_of_key_length'); i++) {
        chrome.storage.local.remove('name' + i)
    }
}
```

Comment: OP wants to avoid getting the entire values – try modifying your question to get an array of variable names described in my comment on the question.

Comment: @Callam: Exactly. @Chay22: Or, you can test for an error in the callback to `remove` and break if there is one, all in a `while` loop. For sequential names, I think this will do the trick - you may want to update your answer accordingly...

Comment: dammit man, how can my english never improved, will edit with workaround

Comment: Ok, I wil mark it as the accepted answer. In the meantime, I tried the way I explained above, but apparently `chrome.storage.local.remove` doesn't trigger a `chrome.runtime.lastError` if the name of the variable doesn't exist in `chrome.storage.local` - it just fails silently. In other words, I couldn't make the solution based on a `chrome.runtime.lastError` in `chrome.storage.local.remove` work, unfortunately...

Comment: seems complicated, but maybe you want to check whether it exists, first? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18673374/chrome-runtime-lasterror-is-coming-as-undefined-despite-of-fetching-an-unset-v