# Chrome Extension: StorageArea.Set key being passed as string

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

Good evening,

I'm trying to save an associative array into chrome.storage.local, like so:

```
var keyName = 'name';
var data = //grabbed from an Ajax call
saveData(keyName, data);

function saveData(keyName, data){
  console.log("saving with key: "+keyName);
  chrome.storage.local.set({keyName:data});
}
```

To check to make sure the data saved properly, I load:

```
function loadData(keyName){
  console.log("loading: "+keyName);
  chrome.storage.local.get(keyName, function(result){
      console.log(result);
  });
}
```

The log shows it is trying to load the correct key name, but nothing comes up. I then try calling loadData(null), which will show the entire contents of the local storage, and I find:

```
Object {keyName: Array[3]}
  keyName: Array[3]
  __proto__: Object
```

My data! But the key it saved with is "keyName" instead of "name". The log from saveData outputs that it is "saving with key 'name'", but it's saving with key "keyName" instead...

????

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

How strange...

Seems my question is similar to [Using a variable key in chrome.storage.local.set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14982560/using-a-variable-key-in-chrome-storage-local-set)

The answer they found was to convert the JSON {keyName:data} to an object:

```
var obj = {};
obj[keyName] = data;
chrome.storage.local.set(obj);
```

This works.

Is this because the JSON field is automatically passing as a string?

Comment: You are right, `{key : value}` and `{"key" : value}` are equivalent, while `{key : value}` and `{key : "value"}` are not.