# how to access multiple keys from chrome extension's storage api

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have 2 input textbox for username and password. And one picklist for some value. Now I want a user to add these values and I am trying to save those values using chrome storage API.

Now each time I am storing a variable as how many records added like counter. 
 for storing I am just using like this

```
 var skillsSelect = document.getElementById("orgTypeId");
 var selectedOrgType = skillsSelect.options[skillsSelect.selectedIndex].value;
 var countTotalRecords = totalRecordsVal +1;
 var username = 'username'+countTotalRecords;
 var password = 'password'+countTotalRecords;
 var orgType = 'orgType'+countTotalRecords;

        chrome.storage.sync.set({
                            username: $("#usernameid").val(), 
                            password: $("#passwordid").val(),
                            orgType: selectedOrgType,
                            'totalRecords':countTotalRecords
                            }, function(){
            alert('Success!');
        });
```

AND for retrieving I am trying like this way

```
var getItems = [];
    for(var i = 1; i <10; i++){
        var username  = 'username'+i;
        var password  = 'password'+i;
        var orgType  = 'orgType'+i;
        getItems.push(username);
        getItems.push(password);
        getItems.push(orgType);
    }
    console.log('==========getItems======',getItems);
    chrome.storage.sync.get(getItems, function(items){
            var keys = Object.keys(items);
            for (var i = 0, end = keys.length; i < end; i++) {
                var key = keys[i];
                console.debug(key + ' = ' + items[key]);
            }
            console.log('------------data---',data);

        });
```

But I am not getting all the stored values. even I am not getting all the values in console log.

Comment: That's what your code does. You store in `username` but read `username1` and so on.

Comment: What wOxxOm means is: `{key: value}` is interpreted as `{'key': value}` by JS syntax. If you want to specifically use the *variable* `key`, you need to construct the object or use ES6 computed properties.

Comment: @wOxxOm if you see . I am increasing the count each time `var username = 'username'+countTotalRecords;`

Comment: @Xan any example to guidance how to resolve the issue

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your "saving" part doesn't do what you think it does.

```
{
  username: $("#usernameid").val(), 
  password: $("#passwordid").val(),
  orgType: selectedOrgType,
  'totalRecords': countTotalRecords
}
```

is syntactically equivalent to

```
{
  'username': $("#usernameid").val(), 
  'password': $("#passwordid").val(),
  'orgType': selectedOrgType,
  'totalRecords': countTotalRecords
}
```

So your variable `username` [does not affect what the key name is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11692699/chrome-storage-local-set-using-a-variable-key-name/40287132).

A modern way to solve this is to use ES6 [computed property names](http://es6-features.org/#ComputedPropertyNames):

```
{
  ['username' + countTotalRecords]: $("#usernameid").val(), 
  ['password' + countTotalRecords]: $("#passwordid").val(),
  ['orgType' + countTotalRecords]: selectedOrgType,
  'totalRecords': countTotalRecords
}
```

This construction will evaluate the expression inside `[]` to get the property name.

---

However, consider that `chrome.storage` allows for more than just a flat map of keys to strings. You can actually store an array (or another object) in there. It comes at a cost of requiring read-modify-write every time you change a value, but easier to work with.

```
// Adding (get -> modify (push) -> set)
chrome.storage.sync.get({records: []}, function(data) { // Default to empty array
  data.records.push({
    username: $("#usernameid").val(), 
    password: $("#passwordid").val(),
    orgType: selectedOrgType
  });
  chrome.storage.sync.set(data);
});

// Reading
chrome.storage.sync.get({records: []}, function(data) {
  // data.records is an array of record objects
  // data.records.length is, therefore, what totalRecords was before
});
```

If your data does not fit into `sync` storage quotas (8kb per key, that can be surprisingly small), consider using several keys (as you did before, but maybe in a more organized fashion) or `local` storage area.