# Passing a variable as a property name

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, ecmascript-6

I need to pass a variable as a property name in the following function:

```
var value;
chrome.storage.local.set({name: value});
```

I already achieved this using ES6 - object literal extensions - computed properties:

```
var value;
var name;
chrome.storage.local.set({[name]: value});
```

ES6 was started to be implemented in release 42 (strict mode only) and in release 49 outside strict mode. According to [Browser Market Share](https://www.netmarketshare.com/browser-market-share.aspx?qprid=2&qpcustomd=0) about 5% still use Chrome 45 so I think it is not a good idea to use ES6.

Besides, I am using WebExtensions to port it to Firefox.

Is there a solution which can be handled by more browser versions?

Comment: You can use bracket notation.

Comment: Isn' this what I used in my example?

Comment: `var obj = {}; obj[name] = value;`

Comment: Can you please tell my what I should change in this line `chrome.storage.local.set({[name]: value});` for me I did exaxtly what you're suggesting.

Comment: @JuliusS. Wait, isn't this code for a Chrome extension? So why do you care if it works for other browsers?

Comment: @CodingIntrigue I added some information to the main question.

Comment: Don't you want to be transpiling anyway?

Comment: What do you mean? Never heard of that expression. Edit: You mean that I should use ES6 even though some users use browsers that don't support it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use bracket notation to set the property name of an object. See [chrome.storage.local.set using a variable key name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11692699/chrome-storage-local-set-using-a-variable-key-name), [chrome.storage](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage#method-StorageArea-set)

```
var value = "123";
var name = "abc";
var obj = {};
obj[name] = value;
chrome.storage.local.set(obj);
```